# Sorting products in a file by price

Tags: c++, file, structure

I have the products.txt file:

```
Chocolate 5 250
Car 5000 1 
Chips 3 350
...
```

As you can see the data is arranged in order: name, price, quantity. I need to sort the products by price. I have already determined how many products are in the file and what is the total value of all products.

I have a structure:

```
struct product {
  char name[20];
  int price;
  int quantity;    
  };
```

I tried to use a standard sorting algorithm but I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first read the data, write it to a vector, sort it and then write the sorted data in the desired format to a *.txt file. The `std::sort` function allows you to define how to compare two objects. You can do something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct product {
  std::string name;
  int price;
  int quantity;    
  };

int main()
{
    std::vector<product> products = {{"first",10000,1},{"second",100,1},{"third",10,1}};
    std::sort(products.begin(),products.end(),[](const product &a, const product &b){
        return a.price < b.price;
    });

    for (const auto &el : products)
        std::cout << el.name << "  " << el.price << std::endl;
}
```

This will print:

```
third  10
second  100
first  10000
```

Here's a [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YLb_KE).